# How to parallelized OWLlink server for Konclude reasoning?

Tags: parallel-processing, owl, reasoning, reasoner

in some articles, I read that they have configured Konclude and Elk as parallel reasoners with different threads. How can I parallelize Konclude reasoning? can someone link me the useful documentation about it?
Thank you very much
Rita

Comment: "some articles" ... link to those articles? Other than that, parallel OWL reasoning is non-trivial. I doubt that there would be a good answer here on StackOverflow - this is definitely to broad for asking.

Comment: https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.090/Publikationen/2014/StLG14a.pdf this for example. In fact, I ask if there are any documentation or tutorials...